# I am getting 411 HTTP Error while using POST method in Java

Tags: java, rest, url, post

I am facing a problem while using `POST` Method in Java nowadays. I am receiving

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Server returned HTTP response code: `411` for URL.

I couldn't find any available document anywhere. None of them were useful. How do I fix it?

#### My code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class req {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sendPostRequest(requestURL);
    }

    private static String sendPostRequest(String requestUrl) {
        StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            byte[] data = requestUrl.getBytes("UTF-8");


            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + "usename:password");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonString.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return jsonString.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your request doesn't have body. So, why do you specify `Content-Length` header and set it to length of URL? Try to remove it or set to 0. `setDoOutput` doesn't require too.

Comment: Doesn't even seem like you need a POST request, but yes status code 411 means content length problem.

Comment: @MaximDobryakov I removed both Content-Length and setDoOutput and it  still persists.

Comment: @Dillon I need a POST because my url is correct.

Comment: Server will reject the request if you are requesting post and not actually posting any data to it. Your code does not show that you are writing to output stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfectly working method:

```
public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            response = br.readLine();
        }
        else {
            response="Error Registering";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}


private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

If you are returning a JSON in your response:

```
public JSONObject getPostResult(String json){
    if(!json.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON_ERROR", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    return jObj;
}
```

Comment: I will try but my URL doesn't contain any parameters for POST method. Any idea for that?

Comment: You do not need any parameter for your url. your url can be `http://example.com/xyz.php`. Create a hashmap and add your post values: `hm.put("uname",  uname);` and call the method. `sendPostRequest(requestURL, hm);`

Comment: Dear Pranjal,
Your code fixed my issue. Thank you so much for your help! +1
BTW how can I add JSON lib to my IDE? I am using Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble, maybe this will help. I did not test, machine does not have java installed.

You should also set all other headers that you need.

```
public static String PostRequest(String requestUrl, String username, String password) {
    StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        byte[] authData = Base64.encode((username + password).getBytes());
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(authData));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(authData.length));
        try (DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {
            writer.writeBytes("REPLACE ME WITH DATA TO BE WRITTEN");
            writer.flush();
        }
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
            String data = null;
            while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonString.append(data);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Handle exception.
    } finally {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
    return jsonString.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try straight away and inform you.

Comment: It is still same.

Answer (score 0):

You should send empty data in body if you are using post method. 
For example if you are using json data you need to send "{}"

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Post() throws Exception {
 StringBuffer d = new StringBuffer();
        String da = "ClearanceDate=2020-08-31&DepositeDate=2020-08-31&BankTransactionNo=UATRYU56789";
        URL url = new URL("https://abcd/AddReceipt?" + da);
        byte[] postDataBytes = ("https://abcd/AddReceipt?" + da).toString()
                .getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Data--" + postDataBytes);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
        // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        con.setRequestProperty(
                "Authorization",
                "Bearer "
                        + "o731WGgp1d913ZOYivnc55yOg0y1Wk7GsT_mnCUKOJf1VChYOdfRjovAxOhyyPKU93ERue6-l9DyG3IP29ObsCNTFr4lGZOcYAaR96ZudKgWif1UuSfVx4AlATiOs9shQsGgb1oXN_w0NRJKvYqD0LLsZLstBAzP1s5PZoaS9c6MmO32AV47FUvxRT6Tflus5DBDHji3N4f1AM0dShbzmjkBCzXmGzEDnU6Jg1Mo5kb884kParngKADG5umtuGbNzChQpMw_A0SyEYaUNh18pXVmnNhqM3Qx5ZINwDEXlYY");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
        int status = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response status: " + status + "|"
                + con.getResponseMessage());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        con.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Response status: " + status);
        System.out.println(content.toString());
        System.out.print("Raw Response->>" + d);

    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!