# Reddit api Oauth: Server returned HTTP response code: 411 for URL error

Tags: java, api, http, post, reddit

I'm trying to get an access token from https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token. To do so I need to send a `CLIENT_ID` and a `CLIENT_SECRET` to the above URL. I did so using Postman:

[image]

As highlighted on the screenshot, I've sent a `grant_type` as a `GET` parameter with value `client_credentials` and an `Authorization` parameter with value `Basic heregoestheencodedkeyandid`. The reuest type was set as `POST`. It worked correctly - I got an access token in a `JSON` response.

However, when I try to do the same thing by means of Java, I receieve a `Server returned HTTP response code: 411` error:

```
public class RedditExample {
        private static String loginLink = "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token";

 public static void main(String[] args)  {
                RedditExample redditExample = new RedditExample ();

                redditExample.login();
        }

public boolean login()  {
            try  {
                URL loginURL = new URL(loginLink + "?grant_type=client_credentials");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) loginURL.openConnection();
                setupPOSTConnection(connection);

                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                String inputString = new Scanner(input, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

                System.out.println(inputString);
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }

            return true;
        }

private static void setupPOSTConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws Exception  {
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic heregoestheencodedkeyandid");
            connection.connect();
        }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing different here, compared to Postman, so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is what I tried adding:

`connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

`connection.setDoInput(true);`
`connection.setDoOutput(true);`
`connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");`
`connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "10");`

```
String userAgent = "test /u/someuser";
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
```

Unfortunately, neither worked - the error is still the same.

Comment: see my edited answer it worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting content-length explicitly is not taken by HttpUrlConnection. So just provide request body with no content.

```
StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();
```

So the method will be like this:-

```
private static void setupPOSTConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws Exception  {
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic heregoestheencodedkeyandid");
StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();
            connection.connect();
        }
```

also i found another way of simply adding one line:-

```
private static void setupPOSTConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws Exception  {
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic heregoestheencodedkeyandid");
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(0);
                connection.connect();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be forever grateful, I've spend so much time trying to fix it! You deserved this bounty.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status Code 411 (Length Required) is sent by the server as a response when it refuses to accept a message without a content-length header, for whatever reason.
A server simply may or may not accept a content without a Content-Length header, and it seems this API is picky. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520070/i-am-getting-411-http-error-while-using-post-method-in-java) detailing a working POST connection using Java.